# Genius G Pen with Ubuntu 22.04. How to get G Pen working?

Tags: 18.04, 22.04, input

In the 18.04 system the Genius G Pen 560 does not work. In 12.04 it worked normally. How to return behavior from 12.04? May be a package needs to be installed?

I tested with 22.04.2 - still no working linux driver.